# How to combine several rows into one with a total figure

Tags: sum

Hope someone can help with this.  as you can see from the table below I have a staff member with 5 "Contract" what I would like to do is add together all the "Hours" relating to "Contract" 1, and the same for contract 2, 3, 4 & 5.

**for example** I just want one line for contract 1 with a total of 8.5.

If you are able to help with this it would be much appreciated, Thank you.

[image: See image to show what's returned]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be a simple group by select.

Something like:

```
select CarerCode, Contract, ContractHours, SUM(Hours) TotalHours 
from YOUR_TABLE 
group by CarerCode, Contract, ContractHours
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still new to this.  It was the group by I was missing but it makes perfect sense to group each column leading up to the column you want to sum to be able to see it all on one line. Sorry about that, mind block.